# Can't figure out auth error for spotify api in python. Seeming randomly getting 403 response

Tags: python, authorization, spotify, http-status-code-403, spotipy

I am trying to get mine and my friends song listening history to do a quiz game.

Here is my authorization code:

```
class GetCredentials():

    def user_access(self):
        token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username="their_username",
                                           scope=scope,
                                           client_id=SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID,
                                           client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
                                           redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)
        user_data = token
        print(token)
        return user_data
```

I then use that token in the request which looks like this:

```
class TalkToSpotify:
    def __init__(self):
        self.credentials = GetCredentials
        self.access_token = GetCredentials.get_access_token(self)[0]
        self.market = "CA"
        self.headers = GetCredentials.get_access_token(self)[1]
        self.user_access_token = GetCredentials.user_access(self)


    def get_user_toptracks_1mo(self, username):
        headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': f"Bearer {self.user_access_token}",
        }
        params = {
           "limit": "50",
            "time_range": "short_term",
        }

        response = requests.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/tracks', headers=headers, params=params)
        print(response)
        data = response.json()
```

When I first run the authorization I am logged in as my friend on my laptop so that their account will approve my application.

What is really confusing me is that this method has worked for myself and 2 other accounts and now it seems to be randomly broken and giving me a response 403 error. The strangest thing is that for one account I ran a this request twice and the first request worked and the second request gave me the 403 error. All in the same run.
I do not see the error in my authorization code though having read the spotipy and spotify api docs I am not sure I really understand authorization.

What is really confusing me is that this method has worked for myself and 2 other accounts and now it seems to be randomly broken and giving me a response 403 error. The strangest thing is that for one account I ran a this request twice and the first request worked and the second request gave me the 403 error. All in the same run.
I do not see the error in my authorization code though having read the spotipy and spotify api docs I am not sure I really understand authorization.

I have tried manually copying their auth token into the headers and I get the same response.

Comment: To add context I have done this with 5 total accounts. The first 3 I did over the past weeks and I still can make requests. So the auth tokens and refresh tokens worked for them. Now I for the last two accounts I am getting the 403 response. For one I got that 403 response immediately after running the auth code, then I ran it again the next day and it worked for one request and then returned the 403 response after that.

Comment: remark: why do you only the token function of SpotiPy, and not the other functions?

Comment: Do you have added the name and email address of your friend into the Dashboard of your app?

Comment: 1. I have just used the token function because that worked for me so far. 2. Thank you! I had not added the new people's emails in my app. That appears to have solved it. I was getting so tripped up because for some reason the program would work for one api call and then return the error after that. Adding their email worked for 1 person, still waiting on the other email to make sure that has solved it.

Comment: Since then, I have added 2 more users. It seems to issue was me forgetting to add their email in the accounts list on my app dashboard. HOWEVER for 1 user for some reason that is not the solution. I can make one api request every hour or so and after that I get 403 errors. This makes no sense to me, but because of the time I wonder if the refresh token is involved somehow.